# Can SBS2003 Monitoring and Reporting service work without Exchange?

Tags: monitoring, windows-sbs

we have an SBS2003 server. Recently I decided to switch to hmailserver as i feel it's better than exchange 2003, so i disabled it.
Of course i don't receive the Monitoring and Reporting emails from my server anymore, there is a way to change the setting? I think it directly interacts with Exchange, but maybe there is an smtp option out there

Otherwise there is an alternative? I tried the paessler monitor on a vm, but i feel it's too much for my use: i just need to get a daily report of the security violations in the event log and something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to make it work.
I uninstalled it, and i gained 200mb of free ram, and a lot less cpu usage (5% less in average)
I switched to [EventSentry](http://www.eventsentry.com/) to monitor the event log and a few other stuff. A limited edition it's free